# What can you bring a double library connection analytics.js?

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce, analytics.js

I have double connection analytics.js lib at the my website, what will can happend, maybe smth problems or smth else?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review [ask] to help us help you. Good luck :)

Comment: If you add analytics.js library to the page nothing bad will happen. But, just adding liberary will not perform any actions